# Application runs on Device but crashes on Emulator?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am trying to test out an app I'm building in Eclipse. When I run it on my HTC Droid Incredible device, which runs on Android 2.3.4 it works fine. However, when I run it on an emulator, such as Nexus 7 or 10.1 WXGA Tablet it crashes. My target SDK version is set to 17 and the min version is 8. Why will the app work on a device, but not an emulator?

The code and the logcat are here.

Code:

```
package com.carouseldemo.main;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemClickListener;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemSelectedListener;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.testmenu1, menu);
// your code...
return true;} // true if you want the menu to be displayed; false otherwise

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // Just prepare ourself for unexpected arguments...

    if (menuInfo == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (!(menuInfo instanceof AdapterContextMenuInfo)) {
        return;
    }


    AdapterContextMenuInfo mi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

    switch (mi.position) {
    case 0:

        menu.add("Product 1");

        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        break;
    case 1:
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        break;
    case 2:
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        break;
    case 3:
        menu.add("mouse menu");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        break;
    case 4:
        menu.add("panda menu");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        break;
    case 5:
        menu.add("rabbit menu");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Carousel carousel = (Carousel) findViewById(R.id.carousel);
    carousel.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            CarouselItem item = (CarouselItem) parent.getChildAt(position);

            // HERE: Force context menu
            carousel.showContextMenuForChild(item);
            Toast.makeText(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    String.format("%s has been clicked",
                            ((CarouselItem) parent.getChildAt(position))
                                    .getName()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();







        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub





        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }});



    carousel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            final TextView txt = (TextView) (findViewById(R.id.selected_item));

            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                txt.setText("The cat (Felis catus), also known as the domestic cat or housecat to distinguish it from other felids and felines, is a small, usually furry, domesticated, carnivorous mammal that is valued by humans for its companionship and for its ability to hunt vermin and household pests. Cats have been associated with humans for at least 9,500 years, and are currently the most popular pet in the world. Owing to their close association with humans, cats are now found almost everywhere in the world.");
                break;
            case 1:
                txt.setText("The hippopotamus (Hippopotamus amphibius), or hippo, from the ancient Greek for \"river horse\" (), is a large, mostly herbivorous mammal in sub-Saharan Africa, and one of only two extant species in the family Hippopotamidae (the other is the Pygmy Hippopotamus.) After the elephant, the hippopotamus is the third largest land mammal and the heaviest extant artiodactyl.");
                break;
            case 2:
                txt.setText("A monkey is a primate, either an Old World monkey or a New World monkey. There are about 260 known living species of monkey. Many are arboreal, although there are species that live primarily on the ground, such as baboons. Monkeys are generally considered to be intelligent. Unlike apes, monkeys usually have tails. Tailless monkeys may be called \"apes\", incorrectly according to modern usage; thus the tailless Barbary macaque is called the \"Barbary ape\".");
                break;
            case 3:
                txt.setText("A mouse (plural: mice) is a small mammal belonging to the order of rodents. The best known mouse species is the common house mouse (Mus musculus). It is also a popular pet. In some places, certain kinds of field mice are also common. This rodent is eaten by large birds such as hawks and eagles. They are known to invade homes for food and occasionally shelter.");
                break;
            case 4:
                txt.setText("The giant panda, or panda (Ailuropoda melanoleuca, literally meaning \"black and white cat-foot\") is a bear native to central-western and south western China.[4] It is easily recognized by its large, distinctive black patches around the eyes, over the ears, and across its round body. Though it belongs to the order Carnivora, the panda's diet is 99% bamboo.");
                break;
            case 5:
                txt.setText("Rabbits (or, colloquially, bunnies) are small mammals in the family Leporidae of the order Lagomorpha, found in several parts of the world. There are eight different genera in the family classified as rabbits, including the European rabbit (Oryctolagus cuniculus), cottontail rabbits (genus Sylvilagus; 13 species), and the Amami rabbit (Pentalagus furnessi, an endangered species on Amami, Japan)");

                break;
            }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent) {
        }

    });

    registerForContextMenu(carousel);
}

}
```

Logcat:

```
2-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity            ComponentInfo{com.carouseldemo.main/com.carouseldemo.main.MainActivity}:     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
 02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at com.carouseldemo.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:110)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     ... 11 more
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     ... 22 more
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel$ImageAdapter.SetImages(Carousel.java:778)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel.<init>(Carousel.java:253)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     at com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel.<init>(Carousel.java:204)
02-05 17:52:31.218: E/AndroidRuntime(1622):     ... 25 more
```

Comment: It seems the emulator runs out of memory: `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: What can I do to fix that? Thank you for responding.

Comment: I don't know if Carousel is a 3rd party library you are using on your own code, but it appears you are trying to load too many images and / or images that are too big. Try using less or lower quality images.

Comment: Or add more memory to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this problem happenes because of wrong xml files.

- Please make sure you only have one main.xml layout file.
- If you want to have multiple layout files (to support different screen sizes) make sure they match, interms of Views *id / types / count*